# bind data to an element on an ng-if condition angular js

Tags: data-binding, angularjs-directive, conditional-statements

I am new to **angular js**. and I have a situation.

I want to bind data to an input element from another input element based on a condition **(checking a checkbox)**. I am trying to achieve this using the
`ng-if angular directive`. But it's not working,

So when I type something into `input1` and check the `checkbox`, I want the value of `input1` to be reflected in `input2`.

Comment: Can you provide actual example code for what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input ng-model="value.one" type="text" />
<input ng-model="checked" ng-change="isChecked(value.one)" type="checkbox" />

<input ng-model="value.selected" />
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.isChecked(val) {
 if($scope.checked) {
   $scope.value.selected = val;
 } else {
   $scope.value.selected = null;
 }
}
```

Comment: your most welcome :) please vote up my answer if you found it helpful